# Use application or activity context in CookieSyncManager.createInstance

Tags: android, cookies

Is it a good idea to use application context instead of activity context in CookieSyncManager.createInstance() call?

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

In Facebook's SDK, it uses activity context, which I think will cause memory leak:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(activity);
```

So I decided to change it to CookieSyncManager.createInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());

Is there any problem of using application context in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but I was just looking for the same thing.

Turns out it doesn't matter what `Context` you provide it in `createInstance()` because internally it just takes the provided `context` and calls `getApplicationContext()` on it. So either way it will end up using the application-context. Here's the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.6_r1/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.java#CookieSyncManager.createInstance%28android.content.Context%29).

I was curious about this because I wasn't sure if the `CookieSyncManager` class would sync/save all cookies in the entire App, or just those in the `Activity` that created it (if you only provided an activity-context instead of application-context). But even after knowing it's using the application-context internally, I'm still not sure about this.

I really wish the documentation would be more clear about what context-level they want/expect.